# Convert complex Scala models/objects to a Map[String, Any]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to convert a complex Scala model/object to a Map[String, Any]
The "value" of the Map can again be a Map[String, Any] or a String, Boolean, Int, etc.
I have multiple levels of nesting in the actual models.
I cannot find a clean method to convert any given model with complex nesting to a Map[String, Any]

I tried the below method to convert a model to a map but the below method will not convert the inner models to a map properly.

e.g.

```
def toMapWithOption[TCaseClass <: Product](tCaseClass: TCaseClass): Map[String, Any] = {
    tCaseClass.getClass.getDeclaredFields
      .map(_.getName)
      .zip(tCaseClass.productIterator.toIndexedSeq)
      .toSeq
      .toMap
      .filter { attribute =>
        attribute._2 match {
          case option: Option[Any] => option.isDefined
          case _                   => true
        }
      }
      .map { attribute =>
        attribute._2 match {
          case option: Option[Any] => attribute._1 -> option.get
          case _                   => attribute
        }
      }
  }

val contact_details = new ContactDetails(Some("00236485766"), "919347439483", "someone@mail.com")
val address = new Address("12B", "sample street", "Some_State", Some(contact_details))
val person = new Person(1, "John", address)
print(toMapWithOption(person));

case class Person(id: Int, name: String, address: Address)
case class ContactDetails(house_phone: Option[String], mobile_phone: String, email: String)
case class Address(house_number: String, street: String, state: String, contact_details: Option[ContactDetails])
```

Actual Response :
`Map(id -> 1, name -> John, address -> Address(12B,sample street,Some_State,Some(ContactDetails(Some(00236485766),919347439483,someone@mail.com))))`

Expected Response :
`Map(id -> 1, name -> John, address -> Map(house_number -> 12B, street -> sample street, state -> Some_State, contact_details -> Map(house_phone -> 00236485766, mobile_phone -> 919347439483, email -> someone@mail.com)))`

FYI : A model without any nesting converts fine with the above approach

Comment: first convert to json with circe, json4s, play-json etc. Then convert the json to Map.

Comment: A `Map[String, Any]` is usually a bad idea, unless you need to produce that type for a **Java** library, this just screams _"I am trying to write my own JSON encoder"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert the nested object to Map recursively if the value is also a Product.

So you need to call toMapWithOption again in your map block.

```
       .map { attribute =>
          attribute._2 match {
            case Some(value) if(value.isInstanceOf[TCaseClass]) => attribute._1 -> toMapWithOption(value.asInstanceOf[TCaseClass])
            case Some(value) => attribute._1 -> value
            case t: TCaseClass => attribute._1 -> toMapWithOption(t)
            case t => attribute._1 -> t
          }
        }
```

Comment: This worked for me